# Basic: CakePHP data not being saved nor validation working?

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, pdo

What I would like to know is a two part question.

Why is the validation not doing anything, and why won't the data post to the database?

QuestionsController.php

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('questions', $this->Question->find('all'));
}

public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Question->id = $id;
    $this->set('question', $this->Question->read());

}

public function ask() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Question->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your Question has been asked.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to ask your question.');
        }
    }
}
}
  ?>
```

Question Model

```
 class Question extends AppModel {

   public $validate = array(
    'question' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty'
    ),
);
}
```

Table postgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
id serial not null unique primary key,
question varchar(245),
timecreated timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

)
```

ask.ctp

```
<?php
 echo $this->Form->create('Post');
 echo $this->Form->input('question');
 echo $this->Form->end('Ask');
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you specify the wrong model when creating your form. The following line

```
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
```

should be

```
echo $this->Form->create('Question');
```